# Connecting Z/OS mainframe SDSF thru ftp. how to get RC?

Tags: ftp, mainframe, zos

I am accessing mainframe SDSF thru ftp to get job details. My JESINTERFACELEVEL is 1. I am not getting the RC for the job thru ftp. Is there any way i could get RC for a completed job?

Note: I can not change any system parameters like JESINTERFACELEVEL...

Comment: You'll have to retrieve one of the spool datasets, (1 or 3) and then parse (not very difficult) that.

Comment: Ok. I will try building a parser to find RC

Comment: Didn't try this because I have a JESINTERFACELEVEL 2 (I'm allways learning) but, the zosftplib have a get_job_infos() function that does what you want.

You can list jes spool with: list_jes_spool(jobmask='', owner='', status='ALL')
And if you need to get info from job do it like this: get_job_infos(jobid, jobmask='*')

It extract's: jobname, owner, status, class, rc and spool

Answer (score 0):

I use this python module to do what you want:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zosftplib/1.0

A little example:

```
job = Myzftp.submit_wait_job('//IBMUSERX JOB MSGLEVEL(1,1)\n'
                             '//STEP001 EXEC PGM=IEFBR14',
                              purge=True)
print "rc:", job["rc"], "Jes status:", job["status"]
for line in job["output"]:
    print line
```

Comment: You have a JESINTERFACELEVEL of 2. @Dinesh doesn't.

Comment: Yes. I dont have rc in the response